# Increase an integer using a button in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Customer Survey app in Android studio.  This would have 2 buttons and store the data on a database Ive came up with the following code.

I get an error saying it cannot resolve OnClickListener

```
package com.example.a2618436.customersatsifaction;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Mainactivity extends Activity implements onClickListener {

    private int Happy = 0;
    private int Sad = 0;
    int i = 1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageButton imgButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton1);
    imgButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Happy += i;
        }
    }};

            final ImageButton imgButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton2);
    imgButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v){
        Sad += i;
    }
    }};
```

Comment: So What is  issue?

Comment: code dont have any int object with name `Neutral`

Comment: I need more explanation than the mentioned

Comment: Sorry if my question was  a bit vague Neutral should have been sad & I'm also getting a red line under Layout.

Comment: I'd also like to know how to add the data to a database

Comment: I changed it a bit, setOnClickListener is broken and imgButton1 and imgButton2 at the top are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly write

```
imgButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Happy+=i;
            }
        });
```

same for other button

Comment: Thanks I've redited my quesion with the new code but I still get cannot reslove symbol onClickListener, not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: can you post your xml file?

Comment: r you getting problem in 'public class Mainactivity extends Activity implements onClickListener {'

Comment: Yes Prakshi I'm getting it there.

Comment: I managed to sort out the OnClickListener there was a lower case O. :)